# как нормально анимировать оверлей для бургер меню

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Я анимирую оверлей очень плохо, путём свистоплясок в JS. Мастера css, подскажите, как сделать нормально без js? ну или минимум js

```js
const header__burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger');
const links = document.querySelector('.links');

header__burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  header__burger.classList.toggle('active');
  if (header__burger.classList.contains('active')) {
    document.body.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
    links.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    links.addEventListener('transitionend', transEnd);
    document.body.style.overflowX = 'auto';
  }

  function transEnd() {
    links.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    links.removeEventListener('transitionend', transEnd);
  }
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const width = document.body.clientWidth;
  if (width < 850) {
    links.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu__nav {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.nav__link:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav__link::before,
.nav__link::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
  top: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.nav__link::after {
  top: 100%;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.nav__link:hover::before,
.nav__link:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.links {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.lines {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.line__burger {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.line__burger:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(8px);
}

.line__burger:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(2),
.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .lines {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
  .nav__link {
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  .links {
    opacity: 0;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  }
  .header__burger.active .links {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu__nav">
      <div class="logo">My company</div>
      <div class="header__burger">

        <div class="links">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Services</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Testimonials</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="lines">
          <div class="line__burger"></div>
          <div class="line__burger"></div>
          <div class="line__burger"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: что конкретно не устраивает?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне приходится visibility руками изменять. А также эта штука криво работает, если быстро тыкать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно!
Просто анимировать свойство `visibility:` с `hidden` на `visible` и обратно.
Если задать `transition: visibility 0.2s linear`, то если задать элементу `visibility`, это свойство задастся только когда закончатся 0.2s, потому что оно не анимируется

```js
const header__burger = document.querySelector('.header__burger');
const links = document.querySelector('.links');

header__burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  header__burger.classList.toggle('active');
  document.body.classList.toggle('overflowX_hidden');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.overflowX_hidden {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.menu__nav {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.nav__link:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav__link::before,
.nav__link::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
  top: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.nav__link::after {
  top: 100%;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.nav__link:hover::before,
.nav__link:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.links {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.lines {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.line__burger {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.line__burger:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(8px);
}

.line__burger:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(2),
.header__burger.active .line__burger:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .lines {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
  .nav__link {
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  .links {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  .header__burger.active .links {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu__nav">
      <div class="logo">My company</div>
      <div class="header__burger">

        <div class="links">
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Services</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Testimonials</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="lines">
          <div class="line__burger"></div>
          <div class="line__burger"></div>
          <div class="line__burger"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```