# Как добавить подменю в меню css и javascript ? И что бы при нажатии на меню, подменю закрывалось?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  openMenu('.toggle-btn', '#sidebar', '#sidebar ul li', 'active') // вызываем функцию с нужными нам селекторами
})

const openMenu = (triggerSelector, targetSelector, closeSelector, activClass) => {
  const trigger = document.querySelector(triggerSelector) // достаем все ДОМ елементы
  const target = document.querySelector(targetSelector)
  const close = document.querySelectorAll(closeSelector)

  close.forEach(i => i.addEventListener('click', () => { // навешиваем обработчик событий на ссылки, даже если она буде одна,
    target.classList.remove(activClass) // функция все равно тработает
  }))

  trigger.addEventListener('click', e => { // тут обработчик событий на триггер
    target.classList.toggle(activClass)
  })
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #57626F;
  border-right: 4 px solid #E0E5EA;
  top: -154px;
}

#sidebar.active {
  top: 0px;
}

#sidebar ul li: {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  color: #dfe5eb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #59e;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 154px;
  background: #e0e5ea;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn:hover {
  background: #556270
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn:hover span {
  background: #fafafa
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #666;
  margin: 4px 0;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
   <script src="menu2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: посмотри https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1122468/331312

Comment: там только меню, а мне нужно подменю добавить

Comment: сделать по аналогии с первым меню, в этом меню сделать блоки, при клике на которые открывать меню. тебе может помочь перехват событий https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing